# For $V,W \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}, r\le n, A \in GL(n)$ there is a representation of $(A+WV^{T})^{-1}$ of a certain form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My question didn't fit in the title, so here is the full version:
We have matrices $V,W \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$, $r \le n$ and $A\in GL(n)$.
I'm attempting to derive a representation of the form
$$ (A+WV^{T})^{-1} = A^{-1}(I-WC^{-1}V^{T}A^{-1})$$ with a matrix $C \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times r}$. So we assume that $A+WV^{T}$ is invertable and try to find such $C$ that fulfills the equation above

I have performed the following calculation:

$$A^{-1}(I-WC^{-1}V^{T}A^{-1})(A+WV^{T}) = I$$
$$I = A^{-1}(A+WV^{T}-WC^{-1}V^{T}-WC^{-1}V^{T}A^{-1}WV^{T})$$ $$A = A+WV^{T}-WC^{-1}V^{T}-WC^{-1}V^{T}A^{-1}WV^{T}$$ $$0 = WV^{T}-WC^{-1}V^{T}-WC^{-1}V^{T}A^{-1}WV^{T}$$
I've attempted to set the sum $V^{T}-C^{-1}V^{T}-C^{-1}V^{T}A^{-1}WV^{T}$ to zero and work with it, but my approach seems to be wrong

Would anyone be able to provide guidance or tips on how to proceed with solving this problem? Perhaps there's a different approach that could lead to a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=W$ and $Y=-V^TA^{-1}$. Using the identity $(I-XY)^{-1}=I+X(I-YX)^{-1}Y$, we get
$$
A(A+WV^T)^{-1}=(I+WV^TA^{-1})^{-1}=I-W(I+V^TA^{-1}W)^{-1}V^TA^{-1}.
$$
Therefore
$$
(A+WV^T)^{-1}=
A^{-1}\left[I-W(I+V^TA^{-1}W)^{-1}V^TA^{-1}\right]
$$
and you may set $C=I+V^TA^{-1}W$.

Comment: Thank you for your responce! Could you tell me more about the identity you used? I've found it on wikipidea in a more generalized form. Is there any short proof for this version?

Comment: @IMM The shortest proof, I think, is a direct verification:
\begin{aligned}
&(I-XY)[I+X(I-YX)^{-1}Y]\\
&=I-XY+X(I-YX)^{-1}Y-XYX(I-YX)^{-1}Y\\
&=I-XY+X(I-YX)(I-YX)^{-1}Y\\
&=I-XY+XY=I.\\
\end{aligned}